# What is the difference in meaning between "photo" , "image" and "picture"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

I checked some other questions, and found that "a photo is an image taken by a camera". But what is an image? What is the difference between *image* and *picture*?

Comment: Hard to argue with the answer above, but I've never heard anyone ask "was that created with light?" before using the term "photo".

Comment: @user814064    But without light, we would not "see" anything. A normal camera can not take photos in the dark. And besides we don't usually ask, "was that created with a photo?"

Comment: True. My point was that no one argues (or even thinks) about whether a particular item is a photo, image, or picture.

Comment: The top and accepted answer points out: "All photos are images, but not all images are photos."

Comment: What on Earth is going on with your capitalization and spacing...

Answer (score -2):

*Image* is digital.

*Pictures* are for paintings.
*Photos* are traditional with cameras.

Comment: -1 What is your basis for saying "Image is digital"? You imply that we never had images before digital format was invented - I can assure you we did. [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/image?q=image) gives then origin of the word "image" as "Middle English: from Old French, from Latin imago; related to imitate" - which is quite a few centuries before digital format.